# Exporting data from MySQL to a file in My Documents

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database from which I am trying to export data using

```
SELECT...INTO OUTFILE...FROM
```

into the My Documents folder on Windows. I would like the code to work in any computer and I am stuck on how to write the file path.

I tried

```
SELECT...INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Users/%username%/Documents/filename.txt'...
```

and I failed. I looked for a solution in the Internet without finding one.

Can someone help me please! Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about select ... into outfile 'filename.txt' and have them hunt for it

Comment: select...into outfile 'filename.txt' send the file into programData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what **context** it is running in. It is not going to appear on a user box (unless the user box is the server). On a server, without a path, it gets plopped in the dir represented by the value seen thru

```
show variables where variable_name ='datadir';
```

Then, under that dir, in the dir that represents the database dir. So for me right now that would be

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\so_gibberish
```

as so_gibberish is my db name.

If, on my server, I wanted it to go to my dev dir off the root, it would be either

```
select * from t1 into outfile 'c:\\dev\\t99t.txt';
```

Note the escape for Windows above.

or

```
select * from t1 into outfile '/dev/t99t.txt';
```

Linux.

If the **context** it is running in is command line, then you have a chance to pick up such things as environment variables.

If the **context** (a slightly different select stmt, not an into outfile) is PHP/Java (whatever) on a client box pointing to a separate server box, then perhaps prompt them for the dirpath (test you can write there), and proceed. As such that client would get result sets and do fopens and fwrites.